# Ссылки категорий в меню интернет-магазинов

Tags: seo, меню

Вопрос до безобразия прост. Но, есть повод для размышления. Предположим, что у магазина множество категорий и подкатегорий. Используя выпадающее меню мы можем их красиво и удобно структурировать, чтоб избавить пользователя от необходимости переходить по страницам в поисках нужной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть с количеством ссылок на странице? Не отразится ли такой подход на выдаче или важности продвигаемых страниц? Если на главной дублировать категории, увеличится ли количество ссылок до безобразия?

Если по порядку:

1. Справляется ли display:none с задачей сокрытия данного списка?
2. Насколько критично влияет такое позиционирование на важность
   остальных ссылок на страницах сайта?
3. Какие могут быть альтернативы или хитрости и стоит ли вообще морочиться?

Answer (score 0):

[Поисковые роботы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82) индексируют по содержанию контента ссылающейся [ссылке/странице](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0), без разницы миллион ссылок, или одна если она ведёт на целевой контент он будет проиндексирован. Если вы забьёте в поиск [контент](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) в выдаче увидите страницу [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/контент](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) но никак не **wiktionary.org** главную о которой вы так беспокоитесь.